# Is there a way to have a dimensionality reduction parameters depend on a previous step in an sklearn pipline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using an sklearn pipeline and I want to do a gridsearch on it. Here is my code:

```
steps = [('vectorize', CountVectorizer()),
         ('dim_red', TruncatedSVD(random_state=539)),
         ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=173))]
model = Pipeline(steps=steps)

grid_params = \
    {'vectorize__min_df': range(1, 11),
     'vectorize__max_df': [i/100 for i in range(90, 101)],
     # 'dim_red__n_components': range(100, 501, 100),
     'clf__min_samples_split': [pow(2, i) for i in range(1, 11)],
     'clf__min_samples_leaf': [pow(2, i) for i in range(0, 11)]}
grid_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, grid_params, scoring='accuracy',
                                 verbose=10, n_iter=100, random_state=89)
```

The reason I've commented out the `dim_red` row in `grid_params` is that the parameters in the `vectorize` step can change the number of columns outputted in that step and `TruncatedSVD` throws an error if you pass in `n_components` greater than the number of columns in `X` (when you call `fit`).

So, what I was wondering is: is there a way to get around this? Maybe if `n_components` is too high, it can skip that parameter combination? Or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... need to use the `error_score` parameter. I did this:

```
grid_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, grid_params, scoring='accuracy',
                                 verbose=10, n_iter=100, random_state=89,
                                 error_score=-1)
```